# mysql get duplicate rows using where

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
pid fid
6   19
7   19
8   19
9   19
7   30
6   30
```

I have a table like this. I want to select duplicate rows,
when I'm sending 19, 30 ids Using an `IN` clause like:

```
Select pid from tablename where fid IN (19,30);
```

I want these results

```
pid
7
6
```

Is there any mysql statement to get these results?

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT pid
FROM tableName
WHERE fid IN (19,30)
GROUP BY pid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

if unique constraint was not defined on `fid` for each `pid`, then you need to have `DISTINCT` inside `COUNT`

```
SELECT pid
FROM tableName
WHERE fid IN (19,30)
GROUP BY pid
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT fid) = 2
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/cea8a/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use `distinct`

```
Select distinct pid from tablename where fid IN (19,30);
```

or to find the duplicates

```
select pid from tablename group by fid having count(*)>1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    pid 
FROM tablename 
where fid IN (19,30)
group by 
pid
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should group pid's and count them, and then take the ones with more than one occurence

```
SELECT pid, count(*) AS cnt
FROM tablename
WHERE fid IN (19,30)
GROUP BY pid
HAVING cnt > 1
```